# Curl request returning nothing

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to send request my api from curl using ajax call but it's not working.

```
<!-- MY FUNCTION that PERFORMs CURL REQUEST (This function is GETTING CALLED FROM ANOTHER FUNCTION THATS BEEN CALLED BY MY AJAX REQUEST)-->>

$ch = curl_init('http://myurl/add.json');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, POST); 
            if(!is_null($jsonString)) { //if json strng isn't null
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonString);  
            }       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonString),
                'signedInUserId: ' . USERID,
                'accessToken: ' . TOKEN)                                                                       
            );  
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

The problem here is I'm getting nothing in $result. Seems like curl request isn't working.

Can anyone tell me, what m I missing ? My site is hosted on amazon ec2 (ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: If you enter in your browser http://myurl/add.json , it gives you something??

Comment: Yes, my api default page. I'm using same function on my local host it was working fine. But after uploading it online on my ec2 instance it stopped working.

Comment: So if you enter to the add.json page on your hosted site, doesn't show anything...it seems to be a hosting issue

Comment: This is basically an add (let say adding data in database) api. when I use this function directly, it workks absolutely fine. But if I can this above function from a php function that is being called from ajax funtion I get this issue,

Comment: Why are you using ajax and curl together in first place??....why not an ajax call directly to http://myurl/add.json ??

Comment: Because of cross domain issue. My api is on other domain and my front end portal that's calling api is on othe place.

Comment: Where do you get the `jsonString`, `USERID`and `TOKEN`? You should the "ANOTHER" function and the ajax code .

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest to help. There was a weird issue. I had space in curl_init('http://myurl/add.json '); Although I have same code on two different ec2 instances (servers) one is working the other isn't. $result had "". I just removed the space and run. and the other server started working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your interest to help. There was a weird issue. I had space in

```
    curl_init('myurl/add.json ');
```

Although I have same code on two different ec2 instances (servers) one is working the other isn't. $result had "". I just removed the space and run. and the other server started working too.